# Show users exchange mailbox from a 32 bit system

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

Id like to query the exchange mailbox of an active directory user

I cant use get-mailbox as our comapny uses 32bit client machines and the administration tools containing the exchange powershell tools are 64 bit only.

Is there another command I can use to retrieve the mailbox information of the user?   I want to see what mailbox database they are on.

Ive searched the internet but couldnt find a working solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run PowerShell on the local, 32 bit client then remotely access the PowerShell remote management tools on the server.

From TechNet:

> Note however:
>   you can leverage the remote PowerShell capabilities that are built into Exchange Server 2010 by using either the 32-bit version or 64-bit version of PowerShell 2.0 (in other words, when leveraging remote PowerShell, the system where you launch PowerShell doesn't require the management tools to be installed as all cmdlets are executing on the server you are remoting).

More information on the specifics here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx